# parted + is it correct to create disk partitions in Linux only by percentage

Tags: rhel, disk-usage, parted, lsblk

we want to create 2 partitions from each new disk by parted command

as the following example:

```
sdg                  8:96   0    50G  0 disk
├─sdg1               8:97   0    25G  0 part
└─sdg2               8:98   0    25G  0 part
```

as example above disk size is 50G and we want to create 2 partitions from each disk

we do it by the following approach

```
parted --script /dev/sdg mklabel msdos
parted --script /dev/sdg mkpart primary 0% 50%
parted --script /dev/sdg mkpart primary  50% 100%
```

is above are correct in order to create the requested 2 partitions ?  with the same size

I asked this since I use the values as `0% 50%` and `100%` , and not gives values in GB

Note - other related links
https://askubuntu.com/questions/507274/how-to-create-two-partitions-with-exactly-the-same-size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, the first place to start should be the documentation available on your machine, `man parted`:

> **`mkpart [part-type name fs-type] start end`** Create a new partition. `part-type` may be specified only with `msdos` and `dvh` partition tables, it should be one of `primary`, `logical`, or `extended`. `name` is required for GPT partition tables and `fs-type`  is  optional. `fs-type` can be one of `btrfs`, `ext2`, `ext3`, `ext4`, `fat16`, `fat32`, `hfs`, `hfs+`, `linux-swap`, `ntfs`,  `reiserfs`, `udf`, or `xfs`.

There's nothing about `start` and `end` so we need to search further through the document. Eventually we find this:

> **`unit unit`** Set unit as the unit to use when displaying locations and sizes, and for interpreting  those given by the user when not suffixed with an explicit unit. `unit` can be one of `s` (sectors), `B` (bytes), `kB`, `MB`, `MiB`, `GB`, `GiB`, `TB`, `TiB`, `%` (percentage of device size), `cyl` (cylinders), `chs` (cylinders, heads, sectors), or `compact`  (megabytes  for input, and a human-friendly form for output).

This is actually for `unit` rather than `mkpart` but it turns out it also defines the available types of unit for all measurements ("*interpreting  those given by the user when not suffixed with an explicit unit*").

You're using disk percentages for your partition sizes. I can't get 0% / 50% / 100% to give me two same-sized partitions, so instead I would suggest that you specify them as precise sizes.

```
# Identify disk OR see the next step for a test scenario
dsk=/dev/sdg

# If you prefer, try with this loopback device
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1024 >/tmp/img
dsk=$(losetup --show --find /tmp/img)

# Create partition table on target disk/device
parted --script "$dsk" mklabel msdos

# MiB on the disk
mib=$(parted "$dsk" unit MiB print | awk '/^Disk/{print $NF+0; exit}')
printf "Size of %s is %d MiB\n" "$dsk" $mib

# Two identically sized partitions using the entire disk
psz=$((mib/2 -1))
printf "Partition size is %d MiB\n" $psz

parted "$dsk" unit MiB mkpart primary 1 $((1+psz))
parted "$dsk" unit MiB mkpart primary $((1+psz)) $((1+psz +psz))

# Show what we have (change "s" to "MiB" for better readability)
parted "$dsk" unit s print
```

---

As an aside, here are my results for using percentage based allocations. As you can see the partitions are *almost* the same size, but they are not exact:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1024 >/tmp/img
dsk=$(losetup --show --find /tmp/img)
parted --script "$dsk" mklabel msdos
parted "$dsk" mkpart primary 0% 50%      # Notice 0% isn't sector zero
parted "$dsk" mkpart primary 50% 100%
parted "$dsk" unit s print               # Count by sectors

Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 2097152s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start     End       Size      Type     File system  Flags
 1      2048s     1048575s  1046528s  primary
 2      1048576s  2097151s  1048576s  primary
```

Comment: from your answer I am understating that you not rejected my approach, but you prefer to do it as you explained, am I correct?

Comment: @yael I can't get 0% / 50% / 100% to give me same-sized partitions

Comment: OP's code works fine here, I just tried it  and it creates two equal-sized partitions on an internal drive and a USB drive...

Comment: @don_crissti I've added to my answer showing exactly what I get with percentage values

Comment: Well, OK, that's true but that minuscule difference is the initial `1MIB` that `parted` uses for alignment. If we just change the last command OP uses to `parted --script -- /dev/sdg mkpart primary  50% -1MiB`  that is, tell `parted` to not use the last `1MiB` of the device, then the two partitions should be truly identical in size...

Comment: Yes exactly, @don_crissti, except that `50% -1MiB` isn't a valid operation for `parted` so you need to unroll it yourself. And that's what I've done with my non-percent-based code

Comment: works fine here... I wouldn't post code without trying it first... maybe you forgot the end of options `--` ?

Comment: @don_crissti I tried all the code I've posted here

Comment: Well, as I said, you can only get invalid option if  you don't use `--` to signal end of options before the `-1MiB` param which in that case will be treated as an option/operation that `parted` doesn't recognize: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parted/2011-07/msg00002.html